# Cannot limit the cpu usage of a 16-bit app using Windows 2003 / WSRM

Tags: windows-server-2003, resource-management, windows

I'm trying to limit the cpu usage of an legacy Clipper application vía WSRM
(Windows System Resource Manager). The app hogs the CPU to 100% usage, then
I tried with:

- Installing WSRM
- Creating a new Process Matching Criteria (TestProc), including the files 
  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CMD.EXE,
  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NTVDM.EXE,
  C:\TEST\TL_BLI.EXE (the damn 16-bit program). I tried adding the programs manually and selecting by "Running Process" and "Application"
- Adding the group "Everyone" to the criteria
- Creating a new Resource Allocation Policy (TestPolicy), adding the TestProc
  criteria, and setting the CPU to 20%
- Setting the WSRM Management state to "Running"
- Setting the WSRM Management type to "Manage"
- Setting the WSRM Current resource allocation policy to "TestPolicy"
- Restarting WSRM

But no luck, the process (C:\TEST\TL_BLI.EXE) continues to run "in the wild" to 100 % CPU, running locally or via Remote Desktop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

On NT 4.0 or higher, increasing the Idle Sensitivity will decrease the CPU usage of a 16-bit process. The Idle Sensitivity can be set under the properties of the 16-bit executable Misc tab.

Comment: thanks, I tried with "Idle sensitivity" to High and the app runs better now (30% CPU with peaks of 80%). But it works only if I'm using the application vía the desktop shortcut, and I was looking for a way to enforce any application to behave.